# Node.js Net Module, Getting data out of the callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

So I tried to solve it on my own and googled a lot but I couldn't really solve the problem although I think it shouldn't be that difficult. So what I am doing (or trying to do) is, I establish a simple telnet connection to a server and simulate the beginning of an SMTP session to verify if an email exist (if that gives me correct results or not is another question)

My code to do that looks like this:

```
const net = require('net');

async function TCPConnection(smtpServer, emailDomain, senderEmail) {

    const client = new net.Socket();
    client.setEncoding("utf-8");
    let completeData = '';

    client.connect({port: 25, host: smtpServer}, () => {
        console.log("TCP Connection established with the Server.");
    })

    client.write("ehlo " + emailDomain + "\r\n");
    client.write("mail from:<" + senderEmail + ">\r\n");
    client.write("rcpt to:<" + senderEmail + ">\r\n");


    client.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    function dataReceived(data){
        completeData += data;
    }

    client.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Requested an end to the TCP connection');
    });
}

TCPConnection('aspmx.l.google.com', 'mailtrap.io', 'new-recipient@mailtrap.io');
```

The responses from the server logged to console looks like this:

```
TCP Connection established with the Server.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP m17si1129948edf.309 - gsmtp

250-mx.google.com at your service, [217.84.87.66]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

250 2.1.0 OK m17si1129948edf.309 - gsmtp

550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser m17si1129948edf.309 - gsmtp
```

So what I want to achieve is to get the complete data (that is logged to the console right now) out of the callback or TCPConnection function. Like for example with "return completeData;" at the end of the TCPConnection function.

The reasyon why I want to do this is, that this function (TCPConnection) gets called over an HTTP Request. And I want to send the result of this back to client. The complete function could look like this (but obviously not working so far):

```
app.post('/tcpConnection', (req, res) => {

    let smtpServer = req.body.smptServer;
    let domain = req.body.domain;
    let senderEmail = req.body.senderEmail;

    async function sendResponse(){
        let response = await TCPConnection(smtpServer,domain,senderEmail);
        await res.status(200).json(result);
    }

})
```

I read the solution for this could be to do what I want to do with my data after the "end" event got emitted. But my problem with that is, that after my three "write-commands" the server doesn't end the connection immediately. And if I would write this:

```
client.write("ehlo " + emailDomain + "\r\n");
client.write("mail from:<" + senderEmail + ">\r\n");
client.write("rcpt to:<" + senderEmail + ">\r\n");
client.end();
```

It is ending the connection before the second and third command gets a response. I tried to "wait" for the reponses with "await client.write..." but that is obviously not gonna work for not sure what reasons.

I hope you get a gist of what I am trying to get done if not feel free to ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I have done it myself or at least get a solution that is working fine in most cases. What I am doing is that I end the socket in the callback of  the third write command like this:

```
client.write("rcpt to:<" + senderEmail + ">\r\n","utf-8",()=>{
            console.log("third command written");
            client.end();
        });
```

By doing this, the server "should get enough time" to answer all commands.

Ealier solution was to count the number of responses in the callback function of the 'data' event, like this:

```
client.on('data', function (data) {
        counterResponses++;
        console.log("Response Nr: " + counterResponses + '\r\n' + data);
        completeData.push(data);

        if (counterResponses === 4){
            console.log("4 responses received end connection");
            client.end();
        }
    });
```

Since I wanted to end the socket after receiving 4 responses to my commands I used an if-statement to check the number of responses. But the problem with this is, that sometimes multiple responses could get send as one. For example, the responses could either look like this:

```
Response Nr: 1
220 mtaproxy104.free.mail.ir2.yahoo.com ESMTP ready

Response Nr: 2
250-mtaproxy104.free.mail.ir2.yahoo.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41943040
250-8BITMIME
250 STARTTLS
```

But also like this:

```
Response Nr: 1
220 mtaproxy104.free.mail.ir2.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
250-mtaproxy104.free.mail.ir2.yahoo.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41943040
250-8BITMIME
250 STARTTLS
```

So 2 responses get send as one. This makes it hard to evaluate if I got all the responses I needed to get. That's why I just end the socket after the last write-command.

In the client.on('end') function I then send the completeData back to the client.

```
client.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Requested an end to the TCP connection');
        console.log(completeData);

        res.status(200).json(completeData);
    });
```

Only thing that still bothers me is that my array (where I push the data with each emitted 'data'-event) is variable in its length. This is gonna make it a bit difficult to verify, if the email was found or not. But since this should always be the last response, it should work in the most cases if I just test if the last entry of the array either has the statuscode '250' or '550' in it.

I hope this helps at least somebody. Let me know if it helped you or if you have any questions about it. Also still open for better solutions, since I am sure there are better ways to do this.